# collection not return values in `meteorJs`?

Tags: meteor

I need help for, in **meteorJs collection not return values**. Here below showing my code where i did a mistake please verify and suggest me.

```
Collection name:
hcare_users = new Meteor.Collection("hcare_users");

Html Code:
<template name="client">
    <tbody>
        {{#each clientList}}
             <tr>
                <td><div>{{userid}}</div></td>
            <td><div>{{firstname}}</div></td>
            <td><div>{{lastname}}</div></td>
            <td><div style="float:left;">{{bday}}/</div><div style="float:left;">{{bmonth}}/</div><div style="float:left;">{{byear}}</div></td>
            <td>
             <div>{{address}}</div></br>
             <div>{{city}}</div></br>
             <div>{{state}}</div></br>
             <div>{{country}}</div></br>
             <div>{{phoneno}}</div></br>
             <div>{{zipcode}}</div></br>
            </td>
            <td><div>{{ssn}}</div></td>
            <td><div>{{permissions}}</div></td>
               </tr>

         {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </template>
    JS Code:
         Template.client.clientList = function () 
            {       
                return hcare_users.find();

        };
```

Comment: and the html code is within a template called `client`? I can't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: have you verified that the collection is not empty?

Comment: I am checking in mongoDb the values are is there in hcare_users but it return to display the values as mentioned the above code didn't working.@ Christian Fritz

Comment: Do you have publish / subscribe channel in place, or autopublish package?

Comment: I am not using autopublish package @Hubert OG

Comment: Thanq it is working I am  adding  auto-publish package @Hubert OG

Comment: Are you sure autopublish is what you want to use?  That gives the client a copy of your entire database?  For a small app this is ok, but there will be security/scaling issues if you want to use this in production code.

Comment: Indeed - in the long run, it's FAR better to create proper pub / sub channels, and remove autopublish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can publish and subscribe to a collection without the autopublish package (highly recommended as it has security and performance benefits)

**Server Publication**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // publish entire hcare_users collection
    Meteor.publish('hcareUsers', function() {
        return hcare_users.find({});
    });
}
```

**Client Subscription**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    //subscribe to the published collection
    Meteor.subscribe('hcareUsers');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add auto-publish package for meteor app it returns collection values where you want to display the collection details.